# AttributeError: module 'pandas.core.strings' has no attribute 'StringMethods' when importing Dask

Tags: pandas, dask, dask-distributed, dask-dataframe

I am getting the error stated in the question title when trying to import `dask.dataframe` interface, even though `import dask` works.

My current version of dask is `2022.7.0`. What might be the problem?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As it turns out, the problem was with version compatibility issues between Pandas and Dask. `StringMethods` is a part of Pandas' string handling functionality, which is used by Dask DataFrames.

However, I didn't know that this attribute was not available in older versions of Pandas.

I updated both libraries and the error was gone:

```
pip install --upgrade pandas "dask[complete]"
```

Comment: Can I do this with Conda?

Comment: I have the same problem. Could you state which versions you are using in the working configurations?

Comment: @gumdropsteve just posted a solution for conda

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue in my conda environment, and my pandas version was up to date. It turns out the solution was with my dask version: we need to install dask via the conda forge channel instead of the standard channel. When you install dask via the standard channel, it only installs up to version 2022.7.0 (as of today). If you install via the conda forge channel, it will do the more recent versions (e.g. 2023.30.0).

In short, the solution for a conda environment is to run:

```
conda install dask -c conda-forge
```