# dask import errors, dataframe/client - version conflicts with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dask, dask-distributed, dask-dataframe

Not all versions of `dask.dataframe` and `pandas` are compatible. This has been already addressed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76322899/8580469)

I have tried several combinations but in combinations with more recent dask versions, where I get `dask.dataframe` working (e.g. `dask 2023.2.0` and `pandas 2.1.2` in `Python 3.10.12`), I run into problems with the import of the Client:

`from distributed import Client`

```
  File "/mypath/progs/myprog.py", line 16, in <module> 
    from distributed import Client
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/distributed/__init__.py", line 23, in <module> 
    from .deploy import Adaptive, LocalCluster, SpecCluster, SSHCluster 
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/distributed/deploy/__init__.py", line 5, in <module> 
    from .local import LocalCluster 
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/distributed/deploy/local.py", line 15, in <module> 
    from .utils import nprocesses_nthreads 
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/distributed/deploy/utils.py", line 4, in <module> 
    from dask.utils import factors 
ImportError: cannot import name 'factors' from 'dask.utils' (/mypath/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dask/utils.py)
```

I don't really think this is still related to pandas but who knows...

**Does anybody have an idea what is going on here and how to be able to import both dask.dataframe and the Client?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If possible, update the `distributed` to the same version as `dask` (they are released at about the same time).

Comment: Oh my... that was too simple. I completely overlooked the `distributed` package. Thanks!

Comment: I updated both packages simultaneously with `pip install --upgrade dask distributed` and importing works as expected.